# Connecting phpMyAdmin in XAMPP with Laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp

i tried to attach phpMyAdmin in my XAMPP server with my Laravel project and i failed , every time i make :

```
php artisan migrate
```

This error occurs:

```
[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

- This is my `.env` file :

  ```
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
  DB_HOST=localhost
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=laravel
  DB_USERNAME=root
  DB_PASSWORD=''
  ```
- This is my `database.php` file :

  ```
  'mysql' => [
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
      'database' => 'laravel',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'unix_socket' =>  '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
      'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      'prefix' => '',
      'strict' => true,
      'engine' => null,

  ],
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to connect to MYSQL with a socket file which cannot be found given the path provided. Change the path to the `mysql.sock` file

Comment: change `mysqli.default_host` in your php.ini file to point to the path `/tmp/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 0):

Open the config/database.php file and edit the MySQL Connection settings

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'laravel',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
]
```